# Textareas causing problems to redirect to the next page

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database that is linked with the php. When I'm writing the first code, my web page gets redirected to the page 'mypage1.php'. But when I'm writing the second code, which is almost(exactly) the same, it doesn't get redirected to the mypage1.php. In the table inside my database, I have Orderid's that I'm using to relate to the php code. Could you tell me why doesn't the second code redirects to the same page? (It stays on the same page). The web page gets redirected to the mypage1.php when I am removing the text areas code from the 2nd code, particularly when I'm removing this code:

```
<input type='textarea' name='staffname'>
            </td><td>
            <input type='textarea' name='Time'>
            </td><td>
            <input type='textarea' name='custdetail'>
            </td><td>
            <input type='textarea' name='orderId'>
```

CODE 1 (PHP CODE):
    echo "";

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>idSpatula</td><td>Qauntity</td><td>Staff Name</td><td>Staff Id</td><td>Customer Details</d><td>Order Id</td>";
echo "</tr>";

echo "<tr>";

echo "<form >";
echo "<td>" ."Spatula Id=3"."</td><td>

    <input type='textarea' name='3'>

    </td><td>
        <input type='textarea' name='staffname'>
        </td><td>
        <input type='textarea' name='Time'>
        </td><td>
        <input type='textarea' name='custdetail'>
        </td><td>
        <input type='textarea' name='orderId'>

        <input type='submit' id='submit' value='submit'>
        </td>

</form>";



echo "</tr>";

echo "</table>";




echo "</br>";

if(isset($_GET['3'])){
     // means submit clicked!

    $queryy3=0;
    $queryy3 = $_GET['3'];





        header('Location: mypage1.php'); 

        $sqll3 = "UPDATE Spatula SET  QuantityInStock=QuantityInStock-$queryy3  WHERE idSpatula=3 and QuantityInStock>0";
    $sqlorder3 = "insert into `Order`(idOrder, RequestedTime, ResponsibleStaffMember, CustomerDetails) values (3,'1987-04-20 11:34:09','Shubhams','tell')";

        $result1003 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT QuantityInStock FROM Spatula where idSpatula=3");


    mysqli_query($con, $sqlorder2);


       if (mysqli_query($con, $sqll3) & $col1003['QuantityInStock']!=0 ) {
            //$sql = "UPDATE Spatula SET  QuantityInStock=QuantityInStock-$query  WHERE idSpatula= and QuantityInStock>0";
        echo "Updated"; 
        }
      while($col1003 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1003)) {
        echo $col1003['QuantityInStock'];
        if ($col1003['QuantityInStock']<=0){
              header('Location: mypage2.php'); 
         }
       }



      }
```

CODE 2:

```
echo "<table border='1'>";

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>idSpatula</td><td>Qauntity</td><td>Staff Name</td><td>Staff Id</td><td>Customer Details</d><td>Order Id</td>";
echo "</tr>";

echo "<tr>";

echo "<form >";
echo "<td>" ."Spatula Id=4"."</td><td>

    <input type='textarea' name='4'>

    </td><td>
        <input type='textarea' name='staffname'>
        </td><td>
        <input type='textarea' name='Time'>
        </td><td>
        <input type='textarea' name='custdetail'>
        </td><td>
        <input type='textarea' name='orderId'>
        </td>
    <input type='submit' id='submit' value='submit'>

</form>";



echo "</tr>";

echo "</table>";







if(isset($_GET['4'])){
     // means submit clicked!

    $queryy4=0;
    $queryy4 = $_GET['4'];




        header('Location: mypage1.php'); 

        $sqll4 = "UPDATE Spatula SET  QuantityInStock=QuantityInStock-$queryy4  WHERE idSpatula=4 and QuantityInStock>0";
    $sqlorder4 = "insert into `Order`(idOrder, RequestedTime, ResponsibleStaffMember, CustomerDetails) values (5,'1987-04-20 11:34:09','Shusss','tss')";

        $result1004 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT QuantityInStock FROM Spatula where idSpatula=4");


    mysqli_query($con, $sqlorder4);


       if (mysqli_query($con, $sqll4) & $col1004['QuantityInStock']!=0 ) {

        echo "Updated"; 
        }
      while($col1004 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1004)) {
        echo $col1004['QuantityInStock'];
        if ($col1004['QuantityInStock']<=0){
              header('Location: mypage2.php'); 
         }
       }



      }
```

Comment: You can't send headers after output. If you enabled warnings, you would've known the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Comment: It doesn't help. I've removed the print statement!

Comment: The entire form before the if statement is output! Every `echo()` is output! Wrap those in a better if-statement like `if(!isset($_GET['4'])){ echo.. } else { header()`.

Comment: The first code gets redirected. Why do you think does that happen? Unless I use the textareas, I can't get its value to use the if statement that redirects to the mypage1.php if the if statement is true.

Comment: Unless you didn't include the entire code, that first one shouldn't redirect either.

Comment: I don't see any difference, but try this code instead. Check the comments I've added to it! http://pastebin.com/U2Wwb2wX

Comment: Wait.. now I actually see what is going on. You have 2 `header('Location: .. ')`; in there. Of course that's gonna cause trouble..

Comment: But that the other header location would work only on a certain situation.

Comment: I tried even your code, still didn't help.